# AKS add non Azure Node

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

We are looking into migrating all our company services to Kubernetes. Since it seems to be pretty straight forward to setup I was looking into Azure Kubernetes Service.

Out of curiosity and with certain privacy issues in mind, I was wondering if it is possible to add self-hosted nodes to the Azure Kubernetes cluster and if so, how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. All nodes in the cluster must run in Azure and are managed by the AKS service, though they reside in your subscription.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Arc enables you to use Azure anywhere.

> Azure Arc-enabled Kubernetes allows you to attach Kubernetes clusters
> running anywhere so that you can manage and configure them in Azure.
> By managing all of your Kubernetes resources in a single control
> plane, you can enable a more consistent development and operation
> experience to run cloud-native apps anywhere and on any Kubernetes
> platform.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/kubernetes/overview
https://blog.tomkerkhove.be/2021/05/25/azure-application-services-with-azure-arc-leverages-azure-paas-anywhere/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/kubernetes/quickstart-connect-cluster?tabs=azure-cli